# PHP converts Warnings to Fatal Errors

Tags: php, fatal-error

Suddenly, PHP starts converting common warnings to fatal errors (and thus I'm getting 500's).

Examples:

```
Fatal error: Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in [...]
Fatal error: Module 'xdebug' already loaded in [...]
```

Any clues on how to resolve this issue? I can't find out if a php.ini value was changed that can affect this.

Comment: Put `php.sparta_mode Off` to the php.ini

Comment: @zerkms: You, sir, just made my day.

Comment: now seriously: try to look for http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php in the code, that catches everything and throws Fatal instead

Comment: @zerkms I found some place in the framework where the handler is set plus a custom error_reporting() level, however I'm unable to get rid of the issue even though I've changed the error_reporting mask.

Comment: It's driving me crazy, that's not the place the 500 originates from, even if I disable that error handling bit, it still comes through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved by editing configuration files, replacing # comments and disabling duplicate module entries.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a [custom exception handler](http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-error-handler.php) in place. Reset with

```
restore_exception_handler();
```

If that works, find out where and why you had a custom handler.

If that does not work, check your php.ini for lines containing "degug", especially make sure that you do not have "xdebug" changing error handling. If you don´t know where to find your php.ini: use

```
phpinfo();
```

Comment: This doesn't help much. We have already explored this if you look at the comments below my Q.